# A Riemann Hilbert problem on the unit square

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions

Let $p_0=0$, $p_1=1$, $p_2=1+i$ and $p_3=i$ be the four vertices of a square $Q$ on the complex plane $\mathbb C$.
Let $f \in C^{\infty}_c((0,1))$ and consider the following Riemann-Hilbert problem on $Q$:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}F=0,\quad \text{on $Q$},$$
subject to
$$ \textrm{Re}\{F\}(t,0)=f(t) \quad \text{for $t \in (0,1)$}$$
and $$\textrm{Re}\{F\}_{|_{\partial Q\setminus (0,1)}}=0.$$
Does there exist a solution to this problem?

Comment: This does not look like a true Riemann–Hilbert problem: simply extend the boundary values to a harmonic function in the unit square to get the real part of $F$, and set the imaginary part of $F$ to be equal to the harmonic conjugate of the real part. Am I missing something?